# Append / Push or Update Jsonb array inside object

Tags: arrays, postgresql, object, jsonb

So i got the following schema in postgresql (version 12)

```
-- items table
CREATE TABLE items
(
    id          CHAR(27) PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL DEFAULT new_ksuid(),
    name        TEXT                     NOT NULL,
    item_code VARCHAR(120)             NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    qty_loc     JSONB                    NOT NULL DEFAULT '{
      "whQty": []
    }',
    categories  TEXT[],
    upper       INTEGER                  NOT NULL DEFAULT 999,
    under       INTEGER                  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    price_max   DECIMAL(20, 2),
    price_min   DECIMAL(20, 2),
    price_avg   DECIMAL(20, 2),
    created_at  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    existed     BOOLEAN                  NOT NULL DEFAULT false
);
CREATE INDEX idx_name_items ON items USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX idx_item_code_items ON items USING gin (item_code gin_trgm_ops);
```

and the following function

```
CREATE
    OR REPLACE FUNCTION upd_item_amount(wh_id CHAR(27),
                                        item_id CHAR(27),
                                        qty NUMERIC) RETURNS VOID
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
'
    DECLARE
        entry items%ROWTYPE;
    BEGIN
        SELECT EXISTS(
                       (SELECT id
                        INTO entry
                        FROM items, jsonb_array_elements(items.qty_loc -> ''whQty'')
                        WHERE value ? ''whId''
                          AND value ->> ''whId'' = wh_id
                          AND items.id = item_id)
                   );
        IF FOUND THEN
            WITH whq_idx AS (
                WITH whq AS (
                    WITH QTY_LOC_AGG AS (
                        SELECT jsonb_agg(value) AS loc
                        FROM items,
                            jsonb_array_elements(qty_loc -> ''whQty'')
                    )
                    SELECT items.id, loc
                    FROM items,
                         QTY_LOC_AGG
                )
                SELECT (''{'' || index - 1 || '',qty}'')::text[] as path
                FROM whq,
                     jsonb_array_elements(whq.loc) WITH ORDINALITY arr(wh_quantity, index)
                WHERE (wh_quantity ->> ''whId'') = wh_id
                  AND whq.id = item_id
            )
            UPDATE items
            SET qty_loc = jsonb_build_object(''whQty'',
                                             jsonb_set(qty_loc -> ''whQty'', whq_idx.path, qty, false)
                )
            FROM whq_idx
            WHERE items.id = item_id;
        ELSE
            UPDATE items
            SET qty_loc = jsonb_build_object(''whQty'',
                                             jsonb_set(qty_loc -> ''whQty'',
                                                       qty_loc -> ''whQty'' || ''{"whId": wh_id, "qty": qty}''
                                                 )
                )
            WHERE items.id = item_id;

        END IF;
    END';
```

In interactive psql i could do the UPDATE items from the first IF statement just fine, using the following sql statement:

```
 WITH whq_idx AS (
                WITH whq AS (
                    WITH QTY_LOC_AGG AS (
                        SELECT jsonb_agg(value) AS loc
                        FROM items,
                            jsonb_array_elements(qty_loc -> ''whQty'')
                    )
                    SELECT items.id, loc
                    FROM items,
                         QTY_LOC_AGG
                )
                SELECT (''{'' || index - 1 || '',qty}'')::text[] as path
                FROM whq,
                     jsonb_array_elements(whq.loc) WITH ORDINALITY arr(wh_quantity, index)
                WHERE (wh_quantity ->> ''whId'') = wh_id
                  AND whq.id = item_id
            )
            UPDATE items
-- The error points to the following statement
            SET qty_loc = jsonb_build_object(''whQty'',
                                             jsonb_set(qty_loc -> ''whQty'', whq_idx.path, qty, false)
                )
-- ^^^
            FROM whq_idx
            WHERE items.id = item_id;
```

but when i call it (the function) via "SELECT upd_item_amount('warehouseID', 'itemID', amount_of_item)" i got the following error:

```
ERROR: function jsonb_set(jsonb, text[], numeric, boolean) does not exist

HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

the error points to the bold part in my code.

Can somebody point me to the right direction? Appreciate any help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ERROR: function jsonb_set(jsonb, text[], numeric, boolean) does not
>   exist
>
> HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might
>   need to add explicit type casts

You pass jsonb_set "qty" as the 3rd argument, which is of numeric type.  But jsonb_set takes a JSONB as its third argument.  PostgreSQL refuses to implicitly convert numeric to jsonb.  You could specify this as `"qty"::text::jsonb` to force the conversion to occur.